# Html5 canvas translate and scale

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, scale

Here I have coordinates lat and lng, this coordinates is decimal numbers, and I want to show path from points:

```
var pts = [{"X":52.67528921580262,"Y":8.373513221740723},{"X":52.6759657545252,"Y":8.374114036560059},{"X":52.682574466310314,"Y":8.37256908416748}, {"X":52.68356308524067,"Y":8.373942375183105},{"X":52.68293869694087,"Y":8.375487327575684},{"X":52.67685044320001, "Y":8.376259803771973},{"X":52.6756535071859,"Y":8.379607200622559},{"X":52.676017795531436,"Y":8.382096290588379},{"X":52.68101344348877, "Y":8.380722999572754},{"X":52.68351105322329, "Y":8.383641242980957}];
```

on google map this looks like this:
[image]

Now I want to scale my html5 canvas to show this coordinates and line as you can see on image above... so in same proportion (ratio).

I try to use translate and scale functions and I write:

```
ctx.scale(100,100);
ctx.translate(52.67528921580262,8.373513221740723);
```

but I dont see anything on canvas...

FULL CODE and DEMO IS HERE: http://jsbin.com/qaledu/2/edit?js,output

So how I can show coordinates - POINTS on canvas like on image (googlemap) ?
Is it possible with translate and scale html5 functions ?

Comment: `ctx.scale(10000000,10000000)` you zoom your canvas image per 10 millions... Why you must see anything on canvas?

Comment: Why do you scale by 1000000 ?? How can you expect seeing anything at that scale ?

Comment: ok, I ask question, I was try from 1 to 1000000 ... but I cant see my line becouse its so little, values are high precision... so how I can scale and see like on image above ? I change it to scale 100,100 but again I dont see anything

Comment: Does sombody have idea how to solve this problm?

Comment: Hint : there must be some kind of relation between the points's coordinates and the scale/translate you apply.

Comment: but please see my demo: http://jsbin.com/qaledu/2/edit?js,output, offcourse when you change values to integer from 1-500 for x,y you will see line I want to show

Comment: Key concept here is the Bounding box : you need to compute the bounding box of all your points to figure out the scale and translation. When using google map, you need to get the bounding box of the shown part of the map (and have points coordinates in the same 'space').